# Service to Get phone numbers and addresses from a city

Tags: search

I have to create city pages for our website which needs to list some random phone numbers and addresses from that particular city. Are there any Services available out there which can help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a WhitePage API available but I don't know much about their pricing

http://developer.whitepages.com/

Comment: Thanks Max, I want information about public services like               CITY SERVICES  
- Police Departments (non-emergency numbers)  
- Fired Departments (non emergency numbers)  
- Public Transportation (main office address & phone #)  
- City Hall  

HOSPITALS & URGENT CARE  
FOOD & ENTERTAINMENT  
- Local Attractions (amusement parks, zoos, aquariums, etc.)  
- Museums  
- Theaters  
- Restaurants    
  TRAVEL  
- Rental Cars  
- Taxi Companies  
- Banks  
- Tour Guide Services  
- Hotels